# Somehow my account does not show any Active questions on dba.stackexchange.com

Tags: support

Please refer to below screen shot :

Note: I have tried clearing cache, etc.

**NO active questions (All blank):**

[image]

[image]

**Other tabs working fine:**

[image]

****EDIT:** (Disabled all extensions and removed the favourite tag)**

[image]

Comment: This may sound weird, but have you tried resizing your screen while on the non working page?

Comment: Any plugins active that you could disable and try the page without them?

Comment: Have you tried installing ubuntu?

Comment: what does `lynx http:\\dba.stackexchange.com` give you?

Comment: @AndriyM I have disabled the extensions and still the same issue.

Comment: Same problem for me right now as well.

Comment: Is nobody else seeing this??  Or is it just @Kin and me?

Comment: @ThomasStringer Not me at least. I thought that it may have something to do with your filters on the preferences section, but that doesn't seem to be the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like magically it is fixed now.

Thanks to SE admins for fixing it.

[image]